# How to redirect back to login page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin Forms app doesn't want to redirect back from my main tabbar page in Android (Not sure about IOS).

At first "Mainpage = new LoginPage();" is set in App.xaml.cs

Then when login button is pressed it opens the browser, you log in, it redirects you back and you have to press the login button again, then it goes to the AppShell (Tabbar page), using "Application.Current.Mainpage = new AppShell();"

Now i am on the main page where you access all the different pages and such and then when you want to logout, you press the logout button.
Now the app opens the browser again, you press logout button in the browser and when you close the browser it is logged out, but it does NOT redirect back to the LoginPage, when it runs "Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();"...

Anyone has any idea why it doesn't want to set and redirect back to the LoginPage again? Maybe i have to do this different or maybe I'm missing something...?

[image]

I have the following Nuget packages installed on the shared project (I'm using Oidc):

[image]

**App.xaml.cs - This sets LoginPage as MainPage**

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MonkeyCache.FileStore.Barrel.ApplicationId = "OurApp";

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;

        container.Register<IRequestProvider, RequestProvider>();
        container.Register<IIdentity, Identity>();

        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }
```

**LoginPage - On login page, there is a Login button, you press that and it runs this command**

```
async Task ExecuteLoginAsync()
    {
        Credentials credentials = await _identity.AuthenticateAsync();
        UpdateCredentials(credentials);            

        if (_credentials.IsError != false)
            _requestProvider.RetriveAuthenticationHeader(_credentials.AccessToken);
        
        try
        {
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("token", _credentials.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
        }
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
```

**Logout - called in ProfilePage which uses the AppShell:**

```
async Task ExecuteLogout()
    {
        string token = "";
        try
        {
            token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("token");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
        }

        await _identity.LogoutAsync(token);

        _credentials = null;

        Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();

        //await navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
    }
```

So the first click on login opens the browser, you can then login and it then redirects back, but it doesn't do anything now... Like it doesn't change to the AppShell as MainPage. But if you press login again, it then changes to the AppShell. So it works, but not quite as i would like.

Then when you go to the ProfilePage (by clicking the tab in the bottom tabbar), you can press logout, it opens the browser and you press "Yes" when it asks you to logout. Now it doesn't automatically close the browser. But when i then close the browser, it should set "Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();" but it doesn't change to it tho... no matter how many times logout button is pressed.

Comment: Try using below code:

App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

Comment: If you create a new Xamarin.Forms project using the lastest template, you will get a Shell with a Login and Everything. In that example you will see how it uses the Shell to create several Navigations Stacks, without modifying the MainPage

Comment: how can we possibly help you solve this if you do not bother to post the relevant code?  All you've given us is two lines of code absent of any context.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT This didn't seem to work either

Comment: @JuanSturla I will check it out, but i already checked this before and if i remember correctly, this couldn't be used for what im needing it for

Comment: @Jason I thought about sharing some code, but I'm not sure whether or not it would be relevant, since i told that i used "MainApp = "/Application.Current.MainApp =..." to redirect it and because i think all the code that i would have to post, would just make it more confusing. So maybe someone knew what the correct way was to do this kind of login flow or if i did it the correct way, maybe i forgot to add something else... But i will try to add some code to the post later :)

Comment: you also haven't provided any detail about exactly what auth mechanism or library you are using

Comment: @Jason I just added code and a better explaination to the post. And I'm using Oidc with an IdentityServer 4.

Comment: where does the code execute go after you close the browser window?  Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: @Jason Yes, i did step though it, but it everytime it gets to the browser part it goes out of the single stepping and opens the browser... so i can't see what happens after